# How to compute a distance between two byte arrays?

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, statistics, distance

I need to calculate the distance between two byte arrays of the same length. In particular, I am looking for approach to obtain a distance with the following features:

- if the two arrays are very similar to each other, then the distance should be very small;
- otherwise, the distance should be very large.

Basically, I'm looking for a way to measure the difference between two arrays.

**UPDATE**: As suggested, I provide the following additional information about the content of a byte array. A sequence of bytes contains the features of an image, so an image is divided into small regions, and some color information is measured for each region (each byte encodes information relating to a single region): when a bit is set within a byte, then it means that a given feature is present within the region.

Therefore, given two sequences of bytes, I would like to compare using a suitable distance measure. I read about Bhattacharyya distance, but I do not know how to apply it in this case, so I was wondering if there were other distance measures to compare two byte arrays.

Comment: Can you give more information about the type of data in the arrays?  Or perhaps some examples showing the type of arrays that you would consider similar?

Comment: Yup, we need more information here. Otherwise people are just going to say "Ummm euclidean distance I guess?"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the Euclidean distance for this. Basically you add the squares of the difference between each pair of elements in your arrays and extract the square root from that sum.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance

However, there are other distance metrics that could apply better to your data, for example Pearson Correlation, cosine similiarity, hamming distance, etc.

Answer (score 1):

By order of complexity,

a L1 = Sum | xi - yi |

or a L2 = Sum | xi - yi |^2